# Not able to create twitterSourceConnector using Landoop/Fast-data-dev. Create button is disabled

Tags: twitter, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, connector

I tried creating `twitterSourceConnector` through Landoop UI but the create button is disabled.

I tried modifying the properties but still no luck.There is no invalid syntax or any other error.

Here is my properties:

```
name=twitter-source
connector.class=com.eneco.trading.kafka.connect.twitter.TwitterSourceConnector
tasks.max=1
topic=twitter-source-demo
key.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter
key.converter.schemas.enable=true
value.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter
value.converter.schemas.enable=true

twitter.consumerkey=***
twitter.consumersecret=***
twitter.token=***
twitter.secret=***
track.terms=programming,java,kafka,pyspark,python
language=en
```

Comment: Have you tried to fire up the connector using `curl`?

Comment: Could you please share some detail or link about how to fire up the connector using curl?

Comment: Getting the same issue. I am using docker-compose with landoop/fast-data-dev:latest image Then used the kafka-connect-ui to create twitter source connector that @SudhansuKumar is trying to do.

Comment: I have the same issue with Landoop and Kafka Connect, do you find same solution ?

Comment: Till now, still issue from UI. Created the connector using curl worked fine for me.

Answer (score 1):

changing the key **topic** property to **topics** solved the problem for me. You can also use **topics.regex**

Answer (score 0):

I have been going through the course, Apache Kafka Series - Kafka Connect Hands-on Learning by Stéphane Maarek where one needs to setup kafka connect using Landoop UI.

While trying to create twitter source connector using landoop UI, I guess there is a bug which does not allow one to submit the properties since the button is disabled always.

But on the course, Stéphane Maarek does not face this issue. So I tried pulling the oldest image i.e.
***lensesio/fast-data-dev:2.0.1***

hoping that the UI issue does not exist.

But the UI issue was still there. So the next thing I did was check if the issue exists on twitter sink setup. There it seems to be working fine.
So I inspected the browser and found the API call made to setup twitter sink. I updated the same to point to twitter source connector and ended up with below curl command,

```html
curl 'http://192.168.99.100:30044/api/kafka-connect/connectors' \
  -H 'Connection: keep-alive' \
  -H 'Accept: application/json' \
  -H 'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/92.0.4515.107 Safari/537.36' \
  -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  -H 'Origin: http://192.168.99.100:30044' \
  -H 'Referer: http://192.168.99.100:30044/kafka-connect-ui/' \
  -H 'Accept-Language: en-GB,en-US;q=0.9,en;q=0.8' \
  --data-raw '{"name":"TwitterSourceConnector","config":{"connector.class":"com.eneco.trading.kafka.connect.twitter.TwitterSourceConnector","topics":"demo-3-twitter","tasks.max":"1","twitter.consumerkey":"dummy key","twitter.consumersecret":"dummy secret","twitter.token":"dummy token","twitter.secret":"dummy secret","track.terms": "programming,java,kafka,scala","language": "en",
"key.converter": "org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter",
      "key.converter.schemas.enable": "true",
    "value.converter": "org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter",
    "value.converter.schemas.enable": "true"
 }}' \
  --compressed \
  --insecure
```

Now it works. The connector shows up on Landoop UI.
[Twitter source connector](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4L1ZY.png) 
Please note that the above curl command will start a connector successfully only with the lensesio/fast-data-dev:2.0.1 image. It does not work with latest image.